# php mysql queries aren't updating database in for-loop

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, screen-scraping

I'm screen scraping a page with data I want to write in a mysql database.

```
$url = "http://example.com/index.jsp";

$raw = file_get_contents($url);

$newlines = array("\t","\n","\r","\x20\x20","\0","\x0B");

$content = str_replace($newlines, "", $raw);

$start = strpos($content,'<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">"');

$end = strpos($content,'</table>',$start) + 8;

$table = substr($content,$start,$end-$start);
```

The Data processing works well, all the html tags, whitespaces, and html special characters such as   etc. have been removed from the data. The values are looking fine when echoed in the processing page.

```
function cleanSiteVal($siteval){
    $repl = array('value=', '"');
    $siteval = strip_tags($siteval);
    $siteval = str_replace($repl, '', $siteval);
    $siteval = html_entity_decode($siteval);

    return $siteval;
}

foreach ($rows[0] as $row){

    if ((strpos($row,'<td align')==true)){
                //echo $row;
                preg_match_all( '@value="([^"]*)"@', $row, $cells ) ;             
        $fln = cleanSiteVal($cells[0][0]);
        $flf = cleanSiteVal($cells[0][1]);
        $sch = cleanSiteVal($cells[0][2]);
        $est = cleanSiteVal($cells[0][3]);
        $trm = cleanSiteVal($cells[0][4]);
        $sts = cleanSiteVal($cells[0][5]);
        echo 'flnr: '.$fln.', from: '.$flf.', scheduled: '.$sch.', estimated: '.$est.', terminal: '.$trm.', status: '.$sts.'<br />';


        $fliarr[] = array(
                    0 => $fln,
                    1 => $flf,
                    2 => $sch,
                    3 => $est,
                    4 => $trm,
                    5 => $sts 
                    );
    }
}
```

I 'echo' the query i'm constructing out of this processed data and this queries executed within phpmyadmin are working fine, although the queries i'm executing within my for loop are not.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($fliarr); $i++) {

    $nrfli = $fliarr[$i][0];

    $stat = $fliarr[$i][5];
    $term = $fliarr[$i][4];
    if ($fliarr[$i][3]!='' || !empty($fliarr[$i][3])) { $abr = $today.' '.$fliarr[$i][3].':00'; } else { $abr = $today.' '.$fliarr[$i][2].':00'; }

    //echo 'estimated/sched. time: '.$abr.', flugnr: '.$fliarr[$i][0].', status: '.$stat.'<br />';

    $sql = "UPDATE `some_table` SET `val1`='$stat', `val2`='$term', `val3`='$abr' WHERE (`datetime_field` BETWEEN '$sfrom' AND '$till') AND `val4`='$nrfli'";
    echo $sql.'<br />';
    $res = mysql_query($sql);

    if(!$res) {
        echo mysql_error().' Fehler bei der Update Abfrage';
    } else {
        //echo 'Ok, Update Buchungen'.$nrfli.'<br />';
    }
}
```

How do I manage this queries to work in my for loop? I know, this is bad practice and I also tried to do with a PDO layer and prepare my queries, but that didn't work either.

Again, the copied queries from the echo in the for loop are working in phpmyadmin. Why not in my for loop?

Comment: Are the queries producing errors (and this printing the error and some German) or are they appearing to run but not having any effect?

Comment: What is the error text that is being provided?

Comment: try adding `$siteval = mysql_real_escape_string($siteval);` in function cleansiteval.

Comment: The queries are not producing any error, but they have any effect either.
@Blazemonger: I'm not sure what you mean with your answer.

Comment: Try to echo a mysql error:
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
This may show any errors (not just sql errors). It might have something to do with your mysql connection.

Comment: @John: I added mysql_real_escape_string() in cleanup function, but no luck.

Comment: Oh guys! I feel so stupid right now!!! It turned out to be a file permission issue. The file executing the searches was on 644 and is now on 755. I'm really sorry for wasting your time! My most sincere excuses for the inconvenience. You should even give me a downvote for this stupid error and the time wasting of you guys.

Comment: Oh no, I was misleaded. It's still not working.
@beerwin: i edited the code as you suggested. But nothing.

Comment: What I gather is that a perfectly good SQL query is retrieving zero records when run in your php script yet when run using phpadmin, it is returning one or more records.  This indicates to me that the SQL query in your php script is **not** the same as what you are putting into phpadmin.  What happens if you put the same thing you use in phpadmin into a hard coded text string and submit through mysql_query()?

Comment: @RichardChambers: I tried to do what you said, the hard coded version works fine and updates the record as expected. Now what?

Comment: If the hard coded version works and the generated version does not there is a problem with the generated version.  Why do you have SET \`val1\`='$stat' rather than SET val1='$stat' (no quotes around val1)?

Comment: $fliarr is defined in foreach loop , try echo it out side the foreach loop and see if it works , and try also this $fliarr[] instead of just $fliarr

Comment: @RichardChambers: I tried with and without the backticks around val1, but neither did work. $fliarr values seem to be correct. I also tried gettype on some values and is_string to check if they are really a string.

Comment: @goodmood: you mean _this $fliarr[0][0]_ ?

Comment: Just an additional info, in the array are no more 80 items, which generate round about 80 mysql queries. Is that too much for a mysql server?

Comment: i mean in this line for ($i = 0; $i < count($fliarr); $i++) { .

Comment: this gives me a fatal error: `Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading`

Comment: is this variable $fliarr working outside foreach loop ? try echo it outside foreach before you use it in for loop .

Comment: thank you for persuing my problem, yes the variable is an array and yes, if i just type `echo $fliarr[0][0]` i'll get the value of the first array in the set within the fliarr array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it turned out to be a problem with the & n b s p ; whitespace. html_entity_decode didn't get rid of it because of this explanation:

> You might wonder why trim(html_entity_decode(' ')); doesn't reduce the string to an empty string, that's because the '& n b s p ;' entity is not ASCII code 32 (which is stripped by trim()) but ASCII code 160 (0xa0) in the default ISO 8859-1 encoding.

*source: [php docs htmlentitydecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)*

Here is what I did to find out:

1. I mada a full html page with doctype declaration and charset meta
   tag.
2. I chose mysql_encoding to utf-8
3. I echoed the queries in valid html paragraphs This showed me that
   they were odd characters within the spaces of the values for the
   query
4. I added `return utf8_encode($siteval);` in cleanSiteVal function
5. I added `$siteval = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $siteval);`

All these steps finally cleaned up the values coming form the scraped site and got the queries in my loop fired. Hurray!!!! This was a big lesson learned for me. I will always set mysql_encoding for my connections, that saves a lot of utf8_encode around echoed values in dynamically generated html code. And it shows the html & n b s p ; whitespaces left in the data.

So finally here is the full cleanSiteVal() function:

```
   function cleanSiteVal($siteval){
    $repl = array('value=', '"', '&nbsp;');
    $siteval = strip_tags($siteval);
    $siteval = str_replace($repl, '', $siteval);
    $siteval = html_entity_decode($siteval);
    $siteval = str_replace('&auml;', 'ä', $siteval);
    $siteval = mysql_real_escape_string($siteval);
    return utf8_encode($siteval);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your variables in your sql are between quotes , try this

```
   $sql = "UPDATE some_table SET val1='".$stat."', val2='".$term."', val3='".$abr."' WHERE (`datetime_field` BETWEEN '".$sfrom."' AND '".$till."') AND val4='".$nrfli."'";
```

Comment: Hello goodmood, I tried your version also beforehand and it didn't work. Here the version I tried out: `$sql = "UPDATE some_table SET val1='".$stat."', val2='".$term."', val3='".$abr."' WHERE (datetime_field BETWEEN '".$sfrom."' AND '".$till."') AND val4='".$nrfli."'";
 
$sql = "UPDATE `some_table` SET `val1`='".$stat."', `val2`='".$term."', `val3`='".$abr."' WHERE (`datetime_field` BETWEEN '".$sfrom."' AND '".$till."') AND `val4`='".$nrfli."'";`
val4 is the identifier for the rows in the database, I watched carefully if the value is matching the value in the database and it seems it does.

Comment: Shorter, I tried with backticks around the column-names and without. Are there mechnanisms to prevent from screen-scraping? Could that be the reason, since I scrape the data, but it doesn't seem to match with the data in the database, although it appears to be the same e.g. `val4='some_value'` in the forloop and is `val4='some_value'` in my table, but still it won't fire the query. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: how you want the database to be updated ? with 5 values of $stat ? or just one ? can u explain litle more ? and what error u get ?

Comment: use this `if ($fliarr[$i][3]!== ""` instead of `if ($fliarr[$i][3]!= ''`